# Upcoming event will have ended in -7 days

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

On Android.SE, the election has the nomination phase extended by 7 days, and as a result, the ending time of the whole election is also postponed by 7 days. However, on sidebar it still shows "ending in 7 days", which should have been "ending in 14 days":

[image: .]

Will it show as "ends in -7 days" on November 27?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ comes to mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the event to reflect the extension on election nominations.